# Passive Perception vs Active Perception Dnd 5e

Tags: feats

I've seen a good amount of threads about the way that these are used but I have a problem with how some of them work or how they say it works. My problem arises when I have a level 1 monk that has the Observant feat. The monk is proficient in perception and has a 16 wisdom giving a +5 to passive perception/perception checks. Observant gives me another +5 to passive perception ending me at 20 passive perception. With this high Passive perception it would mean that I would always have to roll higher than a 15 to have any bonus from rolling so in most cases I wouldn't actually ever want to roll perception because I would be at a much higher advantage to not roll. ***The main question that I have is about how passive perception should be used for things that might take an active perception and otherwise.***  (by active perception I mean a perception check that uses a roll)

sorry about the sort of vagueness of the question I had a hard time finding out how to articulate my question but I found something that someone else on  a different site put up that covers what I want to ask.

(not mine)

.............................................................................

One of the players in my campaign took the Observant feat at first level (all the PCs in my campaign are human). He has a 14 Wisdom, so his passive Perception is 17. So far so good.

The issue came in when I called for everybody to roll Perception check against a DC of 15. He rolled a 12, which adding in his Wis modifier made his total 14.

Now, this is a new-ish player (he started playing in an AL game a few months ago, which is where I met him), and he is one of the most easygoing guys I've ever met. But we both found it strange that if he isn't paying attention he has a much better chance of success than if he is (passive Perception score vs. much lower modifier on the check).

...............................................................................

(not mine)

I hope my edits made this an easier question to answer.

Comment: What game are you referring to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make sense of having one's passive Perception better than the active one? (e.g. when one takes the Observant feat)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58045/how-to-make-sense-of-having-ones-passive-perception-better-than-the-active-one)

Comment: Hi Fableheath, and welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. I see from your Informed badge you've already read through our [tour]; thanks for doing that. This site services hundreds (if not thousands) of different RPGs, and we require that people convey which game and edition they're playing. Could you update your question to state that? (As policy we don't guess, since it causes trouble to do so.)

Comment: What's your *question*? Also, please take a look at the Q&A that keithcurtis linked and make clear here how your question is different from that one, if it is.

Comment: Do you mean to ask one of the following questions: "When does passive perception apply instead of active perception?", or "Can I choose to use passive perception when asked to make a perception roll?"